# How to display field from database into Shipping Transaction Form

Tags: oracle

There are two arrow on the screen shot: **Lot** and **[]**.

Given the **Lot**, I need to display the **supplier_lot_number** from **mtl_lot_number** table and display it in the **[]** field whenever I access this form.

How do I do that with Personalization?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write POST-QUERY trigger on LPNS block. This trigger fires every time is a record queried from database, it means FOR EVERY RECORD, not once per query! In this trigger query select the `supplier_lot_number` like this

```
declare
    cursor c_lot is
      select supplier_lot_number
        from mtl_lot_number
        where lot = :your_block.lot;
begin
    open c_lot;
    fetch c_lot into :your_block.supplier_lot_number;
    close c_lot;
end;
```

Will users change LOT item? If so, use either WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on LOT item or use List of Values with checked property "Validate from List".

1. WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on LOT item - this trigger fires every time Oracle Forms validates an item. See Forms Help:

> Fires during the Validate the Item process.  Specifically, it fires as the last part of item validation for items with the New or Changed validation status.

Trigger can look like this:

```
declare
    cursor c_lot is
      select supplier_lot_number
        from mtl_lot_number
        where lot = :your_block.lot;
begin
    open c_lot;
    fetch c_lot into :your_block.supplier_lot_number;
    if c_lot%NOTFOUND then
        close c_lot;
        message('Bad lot value');
        raise form_trigger_failure;
    close c_lot;
end;
```

FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE causes stop validation process. Bad LOT value remains unvalidated, user must give right value.

2. LoV on LOT item - create List of Values with select

   select lot, supplier_lot_number, some_other_column_describing_lot
     from mtl_lot_number;

Set Returning Item in Column Mapping to LOT and SUPPLIER_LOT_NUMBER (item names are set without colons in this dialog).
Attach LoV to LOT item and set Validate from List property to True.

> Specifies whether Form Builder should validate the value of the text item against the values in the attached LOV.

Now you provided user with list of values for easier setting of the right value. Additionaly - when user gives bad value, Forms show Lov with set of right values.

I hope this helps.

Comment: User will not data entry in this form. This form is only for view only. Let me explain a little further of my requirement. Shipping Transaction form contains the data from wsh_delivery_details table and this table contain lot_number. However, it doesn't contain supplier_lot_number which is required by the user. In order to get supplier_lot_number, I need to join wsh_delivery_details table with mtl_lot_number table. Logically, is it possible for me to join mtl_lot_number table into this Shipping Transaction form so that it can display supplier_lot_number?

Comment: you can create a view with join of your tables and use this view as the block source. Advantage of this solution is, that user can query supplier_lot_number column too. User change of data is more complicated, but when you don't need it,this is good solution.

Comment: I know that some where in Shipping Transaction form is retrieving data from tables/views but I do not know how to access that. Technically, I am not able to apply this solution as I do not have the knowledge. What is the keyword that I can use for google-ing in order for me to amend the tables/views in the Shipping Transaction form?

Comment: Can you amend your answer with step by step how can I implement the view as the block source?

Comment: Simply give view name instead of table name as block datasource

Comment: I manage to extract the view WSH_DELIVERABLES_V from the SYSTEM:LAST QUERY and amended attribute1 to the supplier_lot_number field from mtl_lot_numbers by using sub query. Do you think it is a good idea by doing this?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Simply create DATABASE view using command "CREATE VIEW" with standard join mtl_lot_number and wsh_delivery_details and query this view